# Excel sum based on matrix condition

Tags: excel, sum

I need to create dynamic sum formula in Excel with conditions based on a matrix table. I've represented an example below:

[image]

The sum val is based on what is selected in the matrix with an 'X'. If the 'X' changes to other references, the formula should be changed to reflect the change and sum the relevant values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MMULT(--(B9:F9="X"),C$2:C$6)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. What does it mean the '--' symbol?