# Excel sum based on matrix condition and multiple criteria

Tags: excel, sum

Following from the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304894/excel-sum-based-on-matrix-condition) I'm trying to add additional conditions to a sum formula. I've represented an example below:[image]

The output that I'm looking for for example for Jan 2017 is

```
            2017
            1
UP      A   1
UP      B   6
UP      C   6
DOWN    A   1
DOWN    B   8
DOWN    C   7
```

I tried with the following formula:

```
=MMULT(--($B$17:$C$17="X"),MATCH(1,($A23=$C$2:$C$14)*(C$21=$A$2:$A$14)*(C$22=$B$2:$B$14)*($E$2:$E$14=$D$2:$D$14),0))
```

but I get a N/A value.

Does anyone know it if is possible to do it?

Comment: pnuts, I've added additional information. Hope it makes sense

Comment: If C23 is `=e2` and C24 is `=e2+e5` then why on earth is C25 `=e6` and not `=e5` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example the number of rows in array1 and number of columns in array2 were equal, five. Here you have two columns and 13 rows. That they are unequal here is part (all) of the reason why you are having an issue.

Also your match function is returning a Boolean not an array

I have a way to do this using matrix condition and multiple criteria but had to change problem up a bit, see photo for example:

```
{=MMULT(--(D18:P18="x"),E$2:E$14*(--(A$2:A$14=$C$21)*--(B$2:B$14=$C$22)*--(C$2:C$14=A24)))"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEvgR.png

You can create a formula to fill the second matrix with X's see below

```
=IF(OR(INDIRECT("D"&VALUE(D20))=$A$18,INDIRECT("D"&VALUE(D20))=$B$18),"X","")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rS4L.png

That being said I don't think this is particularly efficient as you are treating the one of the matrixes as a all 1's so you basically just adding an extra criteria / Boolean with added complexity....that being said u asked for this specifically and I believe that I have delivered that LOL

Comment: But with your example, you need to review the matrix (A16:P19) everytime you add a new row to the data table (A1:E14). That is not going to work for me. Thanks for you insight though

Comment: What you say about the size of the arrays is interesting though. If we can filter the year, month and sector then we will optain the size of the array as I presented it. For example column A as Year = 2017, column B as Month = 1 and column C Sector = "UP". This will show then 2 rows which would correspond to the matrix I presented. Is it possible to create this filtering somehow with a formula to shape the size of the array as we need for the formula?

Comment: I think I found a way, see edits in comments for picture to make sense of the formula: =IF(OR(INDIRECT("D"&VALUE(D20))=$A$18,INDIRECT("D"&VALUE(D20))=$B$18),"X","")

Comment: Thanks that is great idea

Answer (score 1):

Just add two SUMIFS together.

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$14, $A$2:$A$14, C$21, $B$2:$B$14, C$22, $C$2:$C$14, $A23, $D$2:$D$14, IF(INDEX($B$17:$C$19, MATCH($B23, $A$17:$A$19, 0), 1)="x", $B$16))+
 SUMIFS($E$2:$E$14, $A$2:$A$14, C$21, $B$2:$B$14, C$22, $C$2:$C$14, $A23, $D$2:$D$14, IF(INDEX($B$17:$C$19, MATCH($B23, $A$17:$A$19, 0), 2)="x", $C$16))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. If I understand it correctly, you are doing a sumif for each of the Ref. If I add another Ref, will need to add another suimif? I have over 100 references and 30 groups :-(